# Как поставить иконки перед текстом и после в нав.панеле

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите пожалуйста,нужно как то иконку айфона поставить перед словом "Магазин",а лупу после слова "Поддержка".Буду очень благодарен

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.navbar {
  display: flex;
  background-color: rgb(70, 67, 68);
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.nav-list {
  display: flex;
  width: fit-content;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.nav-list a {
  display: block;
  padding: 1em;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

.navbar>img {
  width: 19px;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Iphone</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-9usAa10IRO0HhonpyAIVpjrylPvoDwiPUiKdWk5t3PyolY1cOd4DSE0Ga+ri4AuTroPR5aQvXU9xC6qOPnzFeg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/styles/style.css">
</head>
<body>
   <div class="navbar">
    <img src="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/0/747.png" alt="">
    <div class="nav-list">
    <a href="#">Магазин</a>
    <a href="#">Mac</a>
    <a href="#">Ipad</a>
    <a href="#">Iphone</a>
    <a href="#">Watch</a>
    <a href="#">AirPods</a>
    <a href="#">TV и Дом</a>
    <a href="#">Только в Apple</a>
    <a href="#">Аксессуары</a>
    <a href="#">Поддержка</a>
    </div>
    <div class="lupa">
        <i class='fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass' style='color:#ffffff'></i>
    </div>
   </div>
   
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: .navbar { justify-content: center; } .   Убрать => .nav-list { margin: 0 auto; }

Comment: Вы каждый шаг спрашивать? Изучите основы для начла.

Comment: Да,почему бы и нет

Answer (score 0):

Примерно так это делается, Объяснять то, что и так понятно не имеет смысла думаю.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.navbar {
  display: flex;
  background-color: rgb(70, 67, 68);
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.nav-list {
  display: flex;
  width: fit-content;
  margin: 0 auto;
  list-style: none;
}
.nav-list li {
  
}
.nav-list a {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  column-gap: 5px;
  padding: 1em;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

.navbar img {
  min-width: 19px;
  height:auto;
  width: 19px;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <ul class="nav-list">
    <li><a href="#"><img src="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/0/747.png" alt="">Магазин</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Mac</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Ipad</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Iphone</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Watch</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">AirPods</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">TV и Дом</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Только в Apple</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Аксессуары</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Поддержка<i class='fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass' style='color:#ffffff'></i></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```